# replace new line in a different file with an underscore (without using with)

Tags: python

I posted a question yesterday in similar regards to this but didn't quite gauge the response I wanted because I wasn't specific enough. Basically the function takes a .txt file as the argument and returns a string with all \n characters replaced with an '_' on the same line. I want to do this without using WITH. I thought I did this correctly but when I run it and check the file, nothing has changed. Any pointers?

This is what I did:

```
def one_line(filename):
    wordfile = open(filename)
    text_str = wordfile.read().replace("\n", "_")
    wordfile.close()
    return text_str

one_line("words.txt")
```

but to no avail. I open the text file and it remains the same.

The contents of the textfile are:

```
I like to eat
pancakes every day
```

and the output that's supposed to be shown is:

```
>>> one_line("words.txt")
’I like to eat_pancakes every day_’
```

Comment: You didn't write the content back to the file.

Comment: You need to `open(filename, 'w')` in order for it to be in write mode. The default is read-only. And as @HenryYik mentioned, `replace` does not modify the string, so you need to write `text_str` to the file.

Comment: Why would you do this without `with`? That's a completely artificial restriction which only makes the code worse.

Comment: @tripleee I understand that but I just wanted to try it both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some steps. After you obtain the updated string, you need to write it back to the file, example below without using `with`

```
def one_line(filename):
    wordfile = open(filename)
    text_str = wordfile.read().replace("\n", "_")
    wordfile.close()
    return text_str

def write_line(s):
    # Open the file in write mode
    wordfile = open("words.txt", 'w')

    # Write the updated string to the file
    wordfile.write(s)

    # Close the file
    wordfile.close()

s = one_line("words.txt")
write_line(s)
```

Or using `with`

```
with open("file.txt",'w') as wordfile:

    #Write the updated string to the file
    wordfile.write(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fileinput.html) module in the Python standard library allows you to do this in one fell swoop.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    line = line.replace('\n', '_')
    print(line, end='')
```

The requirement to avoid a `with` statement is trivial but rather pointless. Anything which looks like

```
with open(filename) as handle:
    stuff
```

can simply be rewritten as

```
try:
    handle = open(filename)
    stuff
finally:
    handle.close()
```

If you take out the `try`/`finally` you have a bug which leaves `handle` open if an error happens. The purpose of the `with` context manager for `open()` is to simplify this common use case.

Answer (score 1):

with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you could achieve what you want this way:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(filename)
contents = path.read_text()
contents = contents.replace("\n", "_")
path.write_text(contents)
```